# How to add filename to Lightbox2 gallery?

Tags: jquery, lightbox2

I would like to display the filename instead of "image x of x" in Lightbox2, but I can't find the way to do this.

Any ideas how to fix this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Show us your code

Comment: I'm using the Light Gallery Plugin for Joomla [link](http://tutorial.joompolitan.com/light-gallery-for-joomla.html) and checked the documentation and also edited some code but I haven't found a way to solve my "problem".

Answer (score 0):

How about using the `data-title` attribute for supplying the filename.

```
<a href="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=160&txt=1920%C3%97848&w=1920&h=848" 
  data-ligthbox="placeholdit" 
  data-title="YOUR FILE NAME">
  <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=160&txt=1920%C3%97848&w=1920&h=848">
</a>
```

Then on lightbox initialization.

```
<script>
  lightbox.option({
    'albumLabel': '', // To remove the "image x of x" label.
  })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution by adding 
$filename = basename($v, '.png');

and changing the data-title value
data-title=\"".$filename."\"

to the foreach loop at the end of the script.